# Getting driver for windows HW

Tags: linux, drivers

I've asked this question on Ubuntu but didn't get any hint, so I'm trying  here

I've a wireless adapter  [LINK](https://www.sitecom.com/en/wi-fi-usb-adapter-n300/wla-2100/p/1563), the problem is that I've only got a windows drives for this device, but I really need it using Ubuntu 14.04. Can anyone tell me how can I get this done?

The output of **lsusb**:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0489:e00d Foxconn / Hon Hai Broadcom Bluetooth 2.1 Device
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 5986:0364 Acer, Inc 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0139 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5139 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 015: ID 0bda:2838 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL2838 DVB-T
Bus 001 Device 018: ID 04fc:05d8 Sunplus Technology Co., Ltd Wireless keyboard/mouse
Bus 001 Device 017: ID 0df6:005d Sitecom Europe B.V. WLA-2000 v1.001 WLAN [RTL8191SU]
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 016: ID 145f:011a Trust 
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to inform the r8712u module about your hardware.

Try:

```
$ echo 'install r8712u /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install r8712u; \
    /bin/echo "0df6 005d" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/r8712u/new_id' | \
    sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/r8712u.conf
```

and load the module with:

```
$ sudo modprobe r8712u
```

Additionally, you probably need to install some RTL firmware packages on your system.

Source of this information: [this forum post](http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/post/4105067/).

Comment: I tried you answer but no change